# What exactly is "Hoodoo"?

Tags: justina-robson, quantum-gravity

In the world of "Quantum Gravity", besides mundane, mortal creatures from our Earth (called "Otopia") there are other sentient beings from the other five worlds: Elves, Demons, Elementals, Fey and Undead. And there is something called "Hoodoo", which seems to be called whenever specific rules need to be observed. For example, to ensure that you don't cheat at cards:

> “Questions for answers. One question per game. Stakes on the Hoodoo Measure Rule . . .” 
> Malachi assured him with a smile and from his jacket pocket produced a small handful of recently picked grass. With skilful fingers he fashioned a crude doll with the strands. He pulled a hair from his head and Zal did the same, handing it over so both were wrapped together before being wound around and around the grass to create a separation making head and torso; the hair was the noose that made its neck. 
> There was a faint burst of the scent of old battlegrounds, steeped in bloody mud. A tiny voice said, **“Don’t cheat and don’t lie, or if you do I’ll have your eye.”** [...]

When Zal is imprecise in his answer (the card game is for "questions and answers" rather than money), he indeed almost loses his eye

> “Are you truly demonic in nature?” 
> “Yes,” Zal said coldly.
> The Hoodoo doll got up and began to shimmy with power. 
> “And no,” Zal said, feeling a stabbing pain in his right eye. 
> It sat down again.

So what exactly is Hoodoo? A fay? A demon? Just magic made manifest (but it seems to have its own personality)? Something else?

Comment: [Hoodoo (not to be confused with Voudou) is a spiritual religious tradition created by enslaved African Americans in the United States and inspired by Central and West African religious practices.](https://www.nps.gov/articles/000/hoodoo-in-st-louis-an-african-american-religious-tradition.htm)

Comment: "Who do?" "You do!" "Do what?" etc ...

Comment: @lfurini - That hoodoo that you do so well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the third book, [Going Under](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3287236-going-under), we are told:

> Madrigal broke gaze with Cat, rather grateful for the interruption, he thought, and said, “The Hoodoo is the oldest magic we have. Actually, not so much a magic as… **someone** (my emphasis). But as long as the deals are fair, then we deal.” She hesitated. Malachi finished for her, “But the more you use the Hoodoo, the more it uses you,” he said. “That’s part of its price. Why we don’t use it unless we have no other way.”

So we know the Hoodoo is some form of supernatural being, though we are not given any more details. In the last book Lila and Zal are discussing it and say:

> They shared a quick glance at the mention of the Hoodoo, though they said nothing. It wasn’t something that could be spoken of directly. The glance alone spoke the volumes of their unease about the Hoodoo’s absolute power, **it’s unknown nature**. (my emphasis)